# What does the Wait operator in Rx.NET do?

Tags: system.reactive

In v2.2.5 of the Rx.NET library, there is an operator named `Wait`that is defined as so:

```
public virtual TSource Wait<TSource>(IObservable<TSource> source)
```

Neither the [class library reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable(v=vs.103).aspx) nor [this page](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/observable-operators) mention this operator.

From looking at its implementation, which is a bit too cumbersome to follow, I am guessing it waits for the observable to produce all its elements and returns the last element if the observable had any elements, and if not, it returns the `default(TSource)`. But I am not sure.

If this is correct, then how is it different from `LastOrDefaultAsync`?

What does it actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intellisense documentation seems pretty accurate

> Waits for the observable sequence to complete and returns the last element of the sequence.
>   If the sequence terminates with an OnError notification, the exception is thrown.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable.Blocking.cs#L493

So the operator will block the calling thread (YUCK!) until the sequence completes and then yield the last value.

`LastOrDefaultAsync` in contrast returns an `IObservable<T>` so is not blocking.

Comment: Thank you. You beat me to it. I immediately found the answer after posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the methods are on the `Observable` class, not the query language implementation.

> Waits for the observable sequence to complete and returns the last element of the sequence.
>   If the sequence terminates with an OnError notification, the exception is throw.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/v2.2.5/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable.Blocking.cs#L493

It's essentially a synonym of `Last<TSource>()`.

[Wait](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/v2.2.5/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Blocking.cs#L443)

[Last](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/v2.2.5/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Blocking.cs#L280)

Comment: Thank you. I just realized after posting the question that I was looking at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The description of `Wait` provided in the question is not fully correct.

Here are the similarities between `Wait` and `LastOrDefaultAsync`:

1. Both logically wait to receive all the values in the source observable. But as Lee Cambell points out in his answer, `Wait` blocks the current thread while `LastOrDefaultAsync` does not.

Here is the summary of differences between `Wait` and `LastOrDefaultAsync`:

1. If there are no elements in the observable sequence, `Wait` throws an exception; `LastOrDefault` returns `default(TSource)`.
2. If an exception occurs during the observation of the observable, `Wait` reports the exception by invoking `observer.OnError` but then also throws the exception immediately afterwards; `LastOrDefaultAsync` only reports the exception by calling `observer.OnError` on all subscribed observers. However, on error, in both the cases, the observation is stopped.

The XML documentation that comes with the source code (or even with the binary distribution either via NuGet or through the MSI installer) for Rx explains thus:

> Waits for the observable sequence to complete and returns the last
>   element of the sequence. If the sequence terminates with an OnError
>   notification, the exception is throw.

**Exceptions**

Throws `ArgumentNullException` if `source` is null.

Throws `InvalidOperationException` if the `source` sequence is empty.