# How do I block the current thread until OnComplete has finished executing without the use of traditional threading primitives?

Tags: system.reactive

How do I block the current thread until the `OnComplete` handler of my observer has finished, without the use of threading primitives?

Here is my code. I want that the `Console.WriteLine("Press...` statement should be executed only after the `OnComplete` handler, namely `ResetCount` has finished executing.

```
class Program
{
    private static long totalItemCount = 0;
    private static long listCount = 0;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting Main on Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}\n");

        var o = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Take(20)
            .Concat(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01)).Take(200))
            .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        o.Subscribe(Print, onCompleted: ResetCount);


        // How I make sure this line appears only after the OnComplete has fired?
        // Do I have to use traditional threading primitives such as wait handles?
        // Or just cause the main thread to sleep long enough? That doesn't seem right.
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ResetCount()
    {
        if (listCount > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{totalItemCount} items processed in {listCount} lists.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{totalItemCount} items processed.");
        }

        Interlocked.Exchange(ref totalItemCount, 0);
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref listCount, 0);
    }

    static void Print<T>(T value)
    {
        var threadType = Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground ? "Background" : "Foreground";

        if (value is IList)
        {
            var list = value as IList;
            Console.WriteLine($"{list.Count} items in list #{Interlocked.Increment(ref listCount)}:");

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.ToString()}, ({threadType} #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}), Item #{Interlocked.Increment(ref totalItemCount)}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{value.ToString()}, ({threadType} #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}), Item #{Interlocked.Increment(ref totalItemCount)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you move this statement to the end of `ResetCount()` method?

Comment: Yes, I could remove *this* statement in *this particular case* to the end of the `ResetCount` method, but that would be a cop-out and more than this particular example, I would like to know how to solve the class of problems I am trying to highlight with this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Rx we have specific schedulers to handle threading, synchronization and related.

You can read more about that here: 
http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html

But basically what you're looking for is changing this line:

```
 .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Scheduler.CurrentThread);
```

They're several ways to test/validate a Rx query. Keep in mind that wouldn't be the answer for all the problems.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was aware of schedulers but I must have been awake too long to realize that I used the default scheduler, I am now confused. The default scheduler in the case of a console app would be the `CurrentThreadScheduler`, right? Or would it be the `ThreadPoolScheduler`? From the results this program produced without specifying a scheduler, it looked like it was the `ThreadPoolScheduler` but if I changed the program to produce something less complicated such as `Observable.Range(...)`, it used the `CurrentThreadScheduler` as the default. Why is that?

Comment: I think I understand. If we do not specify a scheduler, it selects the *best* scheduler for the platform *and the operation* as the default scheduler. So the call to `IObservable.Timer` would have used a thread pool scheduler to run the `System.Threading.Timer` on. `Interval` might have done the same.

Comment: AFAIK each operator has a standard/default scheduler in case that the IScheduler is not being provided. So it really dependents of the operator that you're using -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341864/what-are-the-default-schedulers-for-each-observable-operator Another code that you would be useful for testing purposes is `.Wait()`. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801699/what-does-the-wait-operator-in-rx-net-do

Comment: Interesting how one could use `Wait` to wait for completion of an observable. Nice. Thank you.