# Nested Observable hangs on Wait()

Tags: c#, async-await, console-application, observable, system.reactive

In a C# console application, using System.Reactive.Linq, I'm trying to make an observable, where each item is the string result of some processing by another observable.
I've created a simple repro using strings and characters. 
Warning, this example is completely CONTRIVED, and the point is that the nested .Wait() hangs.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fileNames = { "file1.doxc", "file2.xlsx", "file3.pptx" };
        IObservable<string> files = fileNames.ToObservable();
        string[] extensions = files.Select(fn =>
        {
            var extension = fn.ToObservable()
            .TakeLast(4)
            .ToArray()
            .Wait(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<< HANG HERE
            return new string(extension);
        })
        .ToArray()
        .Wait();
    }
}
```

Again, this is not how I would find the suffix of many filenames.
The question is how I can produce an Observable of strings, where the strings are computed from a completed observable.

If I pull out this code and run it alone, it completes fine.

```
     var extension = fn.ToObservable()
        .TakeLast(4)
        .ToArray()
        .Wait();
```

There is something about the nested Wait() on the async methods, which I don't understand.

How can I code the nested async observables, so I can produce a simple array of string?

Thanks

-John

Comment: Your methods are **not** asynchronuous: Wait() is a blocking operation...
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801699/what-does-the-wait-operator-in-rx-net-do

Comment: Can you explain why are you using `Wait()` in the first place?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why does repeated Enumerable to Observable conversion block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041484/why-does-repeated-enumerable-to-observable-conversion-block)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why your code is blocking is because you are using `ToObservable()` without specifying a scheduler. In this case it will use the `CurrentThreadScheduler`.

So the `files` observable issues it's first `OnNext()` [A] (sending `"file1.doxc"`) using the current thread. It can't continue iterating until that `OnNext()` returns. However, the inner `fn` observable *also* uses `ToObservable()` and the `Wait()` blocks until `fn` completes - it will queue the first `OnNext()` (sending `"f"`) to the current thread scheduler but it will never be able to send it because now the first `OnNext()` [A] will never return.

Two simple fixes:

Either change the `files` observable like this:

```
IObservable<string> files = fileNames.ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default);
```

Or, avoid the use of the inner `Wait()` with a `SelectMany` (which is definitely more idiomatic Rx):

```
string[] extensions = files.SelectMany(fn =>
{
    return fn.ToObservable()
             .TakeLast(4)
             .ToArray()
             .Select(x => new string(x));
})
.ToArray()
.Wait();

// display results etc.
```

Each approach will have quite different execution semantics - the first will run much like a nested loop, with each inner observable completing before the next outer iteration. The second will be much more interleaved since the blocking behaviour of the `Wait()` is removed. If you use the [Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20220756/87427) method I wrote and attach it after both `ToObservable()` calls, you'll see this behaviour quite clearly.

Comment: Thank you James, great answer, to the point and informative. I didn't have a good reason for not using SelectMany, in fact that's my ultimate solution now. I tried adding the NewThreadScheduler.Default just for a test, and that worked as well of course. I get the concept that the observables are effectively deadlocked on the OnNext, but I think i'll play around with Spy a bit and try to make this clearer for myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`Wait` is a blocking calling, which doesn't mix well with Rx. I'm not sure why the nested one is failing.

Assuming an async function, this works:

```
IObservable<string> files = fileNames.ToObservable();
string[] extensions = await files.SelectMany(async fn =>
{
    var extension = await fn.ToObservable()
    .TakeLast(4)
    .ToArray();
        return new string(extension);
})
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

James' has nailed the issue, but I would suggest that your code boils done to just doing this:

```
    string[] fileNames = { "file1.doxc", "file2.xlsx", "file3.pptx" };
    string[] extensions =
    (
        from fn in fileNames.ToObservable()
        from extension in fn.ToObservable().TakeLast(4).ToArray()
        select new string(extension)
    )
        .ToArray()
        .Wait();
```

Now, that still has a `.Wait()` in it. Ideally you'd do something like this:

```
    IDisposable subscription =
    (
        from fn in fileNames.ToObservable()
        from extension in fn.ToObservable().TakeLast(4).ToArray()
        select new string(extension)
    )
        .ToArray()
        .Subscribe(extensions =>
        {
            /* Do something with the `extensions` */
        });
```

You should avoid all waiting.