# Why does repeated Enumerable to Observable conversion block

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, enumerable

This is a rather educational, out of curiosity question. Consider the following snippet:

```
var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 5);
var observable = enumerable.ToObservable();
var enu = observable.Concat(observable).ToEnumerable();
enu.ToObservable().SubscribeDebug();
```

Where `SubscribeDebug` subscribes a simple observer:

```
public class DebugObserver<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Completed");
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error");
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Value: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

> Value: 0
>
> Value: 1
>
> Value: 2
>
> Value: 3
>
> Value: 4

And then blocks. Can someone help me understand the underlying reason why it happens and why the observable does not complete? I have noticed that it does complete without the `Concat` call, but blocks with it.

Comment: Does this behavior also exists when you concat a different observable which is already completed?

Comment: Your code is creating a deadlock due to the scheduler used. Try this instead: `.ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)`. That works with your code. I'll need to spend more time on it to give you the reason why.

Comment: @Progman - You're on the wrong track. The each subscription to `enumerable.ToObservable()` starts the enumerable again. Like to `foreach` calls over an enumerable start the enumerable again. The problem here is a deadlock caused by the `Scheduler.Immediate` scheduler.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be with the Scheduler.Immediate, because when I pass it to ToObservable(), both enumerations are iterated. When called without any scheduler implementation however, the code blocks.

Comment: @OguzOzgul it only deadlocks with `Scheduler.CurrentThread` from all static schedulers. So this is the default I guess (when `ToObservable` is called without argument).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've looked at [the source](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/ToObservable.cs) of `ToObservable` and distilled a minimal implementation. It does reproduce the behavior we're seeing.

```
    public static IObservable<T> ToObservableEx<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) =>
        ToObservableEx(enumerable, CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance);

    public static IObservable<T> ToObservableEx<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IScheduler scheduler) =>
        Observable.Create<T>
        (
            observer =>
            {
                IDisposable loopRec(IScheduler inner, IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
                {
                    if (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
                    {
                        observer.OnNext(enumerator.Current);
                        inner.Schedule(enumerator, loopRec); //<-- culprit
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        observer.OnCompleted();
                    }

                    // ToObservable.cs Line 117
                    // We never allow the scheduled work to be cancelled. 
                    return Disposable.Empty;
                }

                return scheduler.Schedule(enumerable.GetEnumerator(), loopRec);
            }
        );
```

With that out of the way - the crux of the problem lies in the behavior of `CurrentThreadScheduler`, which is the default scheduler used.

The behavior of `CurrentThreadScheduler` is that if a schedule is *already running* while `Schedule` is being called - it ends up being queued.

```
        CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance.Schedule(() =>
        {
            CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance.Schedule(() =>
                Console.WriteLine(1)
            );

            Console.WriteLine(2);
        });
```

This prints `2 1`. This queuing behavior is our undoing.

When `observer.OnCompleted()` is called, it causes `Concat` to start the next enumeration - however, things are not the same as when we started out - we are still inside the `observer => { }` block when we try to schedule the next one. So instead of executing immediately, the next schedule gets queued.

Now `enumerator.MoveNext()` is caught in a dead-lock.
It can't move to the next item - `MoveNext` is blocking until the next item *arrives* - which can only arrive when scheduled by the `ToObservable` loop.

But the Scheduler can only work to notify `ToEnumerable` and subsequently `MoveNext()` which is being held up  - once it exits `loopRec` - which it can't because it's being blocked by `MoveNext` in the first place.

**Addendum**

This is approximately what `ToEnumerable` (from [GetEnumerator.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/GetEnumerator.cs)) does (not a valid implementation):

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerableEx<T>(this IObservable<T> observable)
    {
        var gate = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();

        using(observable.Subscribe(
            value => { queue.Enqueue(value); gate.Release(); }, 
            () => gate.Release()))
        while (true)
        {
            gate.Wait(); //this is where it blocks                

            if (queue.TryDequeue(out var current))
                yield return current;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
```

Enumerables are expected to be blocking until the next item is yielded - and that's why there's a gating implementation. It's not `Enumerable.Range` which blocks, but `ToEnumerable`.

Comment: But I implemented a custom IEnumerable<int> and returned a custom IEnumerator<int> and what I see is, when the iteration over the first enumerator completes, the GetEnumerator() is invoked again and (a new one is returned by me), but the MoveNext() is never called.

Comment: I should clarify - it's not your own `IEnumerable` that matters - it's the one returned by `Observable.ToEnumerable()`. That's where it blocks.

Comment: Ok that's it then. (Note: +1 already, before my comment), I was looking into the same constructor using !! ildasm !! and got blind and gave up. Should have downloaded reflector :)

Comment: Oh and the source of is of course on GitHub.. Poor me.

Comment: Haha. I updated my answer. I did write up `ToEnumerable` but, it was mostly non-functional - just illustrative, so I decided not to post.

Comment: This is a superb answer! Gives a lot of insights about how observables work in a synchronous (single thread) environment.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you! The problem became so much clearer once I implemented `ToObservable` - Rx stacktraces are fairly unreadable. Writing up simplified Rx operators to understand their behavior is a good learning experience. :)

Comment: Incredible! Thank you for such a detailed answer!

Comment: Fabulous answer!

Comment: I must admit I'm slightly perplexed that the default scheduler involved in these operations isn't safe. Is this something that needs fixing in the library, or is there some recommendation to avoid deadlocks like this?

Comment: @NickL With current defaults, the library is fairly performant. These are Rx's concurrency abstractions leaking - which is why we had to go back to the source. In most all usage cases you will never encounter these edge cases in idiomatic Rx.